# go fyne filter,even i use wrong suffix,the program also create a empty file with the name i write

Tags: file, go, filter, fyne

i'm learning fyne at first.

i wirte a func to save the byte i write in the edit,the menu name is SaveAs.

i also set a filter to ensure i only can save the file end with .md.so i click the SaveAs btn,input the name as 1.txt,when i click the btn,the error window will appear,but the program also create the 1.txt in my file path

```
func (app *config) saveAsFunc(win fyne.Window) func() {
    return func() {
        saveDialog := dialog.NewFileSave(func(write fyne.URIWriteCloser, err error) {
            if err != nil {
                dialog.ShowError(err, win)
                return
            }
            if write == nil {
                return
            }
            if !strings.HasSuffix(strings.ToLower(write.URI().String()), ".md") {
                dialog.ShowInformation("Error", "Please name your file end with .md", win)
                return
            }

            //保存文件
            write.Write([]byte(app.EditWidget.Text))
            app.CurrentFile = write.URI()

            defer write.Close()

            win.SetTitle(win.Title() + " - " + write.URI().Name())
            app.SaveMenuItem.Disabled = false
        }, win)
        saveDialog.SetFileName("untitled.md")
        saveDialog.SetFilter(filter)
        saveDialog.Show()
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PReTJ.png)

just like this,my error window can appear,but also create the wrong file

i try to dubug,but when i run to this func,the goland will collapse. I learned this code from the video I learned. Maybe the update of the fyne version caused this problem

i find the problem is the file browser in fyne,it has a default btn named Save,when i write a wrong file name and then i click this save btn,it will save a file use the wrong name,then my filter will stop the save and return,so the file only have name but without any content.

so now the question is how to stop the save in front of the save btn work,should i change the fyne code?

Answer (score 0):

When your callback from a file save dialog is called the user specified file has already been created and it is ready for you to write data into.

If you want to reverse the operation you will need to `write.Close()` and call `storage.Delete(write.URI())`. This will remove the file that the user asked to create.

You probably are looking for this proposed enhancement: https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne/issues/1044